# Unable to create custom controller Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found ';' at line 7 column 22

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to learn how to create a lightning page for accounts and decided to follow the example shown on this site https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/lightning-design-experience-in-visualforce-pages-with-lightning-css-framework/#comment-90

When I tried to copy the controller code on this site to create the controller I got the following error: Error: Compile Error: expecting a right parentheses, found ';' at line 7 column 22

Here is the code:

```
public with sharing class LightningDesignExperienceController{
  public Account acc {get;set;}
  public LightningDesignExperienceController(){
   Account[] accList = [SELECT id, name, accountsource, description, BillingStreet, 
                            BillingCity,BillingState 
                            FROM Account];
  if(accList.size()&gt;0){
     acc = accList[0];
  }else{
    acc = new Account();
  }
 }
 public void save(){
    upsert acc;
 }
 public void reset(){
   acc = new Account();
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to learn how to convert my visualforce pages to match lightning format and would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are having `&gt;` instead of **>** symbol in the if condition.. if you replace that, it should work fine

```
if(accList.size()&gt;0){
```

to

```
if(accList.size() > 0){
```